# What are some efficient ways to set up my environment when working on a remote site?

Tags: php, optimization, workflow, sublimetext2, development-environment

Hello fellow Programmers,

I am still a relatively new programmer and have recently gotten my first on-campus programming position. I am the sole dev responsible for 8 domains as well as 3 small sized PHP web apps.

The campus has its web environment divided into staging and live servers -- we develop on the staging via SFTP and then push the updates to the live server through a web GUI.

I use Sublime Text 2 and the Sublime SFTP plugin currently for all my dev work (its my preferred editor). If I am just making an edit to a page I'll open that individual file via the ftp browser. If I am working on the PHP web app projects, I have the app directory mapped to a local folder so that when I save locally the file is auto-uploaded through Sublime SFTP.

I feel like this workflow is slow and sub-optimal. How can I improve my workflow for working with remote content? I'd love to set up a local environment on my machine as that would eliminate the constant SFTP upload/download, but as I said there are many sites and the space required for a local copy of the entire domain would be quite large and complex; not to mention keeping it updated with whatever the latest on the staging server is would be a nightmare.

Anyone know how I can improve my general web dev workflow from what I've described? I'd really like to cut out constantly editing over FTP but I'm not sure where to start other than ripping the entire directory and dumping it into XAMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using source code control?  If not, you should.  I suggest using Git, for example hosted on Github.

For a simple setup like this you don't need to use any special deployment tools; you can also use Git for deployment.

Developing directly on the staging server is not a great idea.  Try to set up a development environment environment on your laptop.

You can push from your development machine to Github.  Then then on either staging or the live server you can connect via ssh and pull from Github.

This allows you you to use all the power of Git to create branches and tags and to rollback to an earlier version if you make a mistake.

Comment: I'm not currently using git unfortunately. This is because the department won't pay for it, and I feel like their code would need to be in private repos for security purposes so I've avoided the free version with public repos.

Comment: @Prefix You don't pay for git it is free and you can put your repo anywhere you wish, it doesn't have to be hosted on GitHub. In fact, it doesn't have to be hosted at all. A local repo on your laptop would give you most of the benefits of version control.

Comment: @vascowhite would a locally-hosted repo be able to automatically upload to the staging server? I won't lie I have not used Git / version control very much, but I'd like to. Also this would require me having a local copy of all of the domains/web apps on my PC which seems like it could get quite out of control. Any tips for that?

Comment: Why do you think it would get out of hand? I have around 10 projects on my dev machine, all in version control. You still have a normal file system that you can copy files from/to as normal, except you are able to revert changes etc. read the docs on the git site and get a good book on it. This isn't the place to teach you how to use a VCS.

Comment: Right. Would a local repo be able to push to a remote server? In the original post, the author states you can push from dev machine->github, then pull github to the remote server via SSH. Thank you for your help.

Comment: While it would be possible to set up a Git server on your own servers so you can push to them, I don't think it is worth the hassle or the security risk.  No, I still think you should use Github. If your employer won't pay, then pay for it yourself -- think of it as an investment in your career.  Compare the $7/month for Github with what you paid in tuition for classes -- and the experience you gain using Git will be much more valuable in your technical career than some of your classes. Or think of it like how chefs buy their own knives and bring them to the restaurants where they work.

Comment: @EamonnO'Brien-Strain: I think I will, thanks. Do you recommend each site exists as its own private repo? Also, I'd like to set it up so that Git pushes to my staging server. can you point me in the direction of any resources I can use to learn how to do that? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: (1) Are your three sites very similar and contain a lot of identical files, so that you often make the same changes on the different sites? If that case you might consider using a single repo with multiple branches.  Otherwise, it is simpler to have a separate repo for each -- though that would use up more of the limited number of private repos that Github allows for the $7 level. (2) With the simple Github setup all your pushes are to Github.  To deploy on the staging server you would remotely login to it and do "git pull" from Github.

Comment: You could use bitbucket or dropbox to host your private repos for free.

Comment: As regards Dropbox, yes you could use have your Git repo in a Dropbox folder, but there are two problems (1) If you make simultaneous changes on two machines, something that Git can normally manage well, you could end up with a mess, or even lose data. (2) You would need to install the Dropbox client software on your server machines and authenticate them with your account password.  Depending on the OS and the setup of your servers, that may be hard to do.